# How can I use NSTask to check whether particular package installed or not

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a requirement for my Mac app to check whether brew or ffmpeg are installed or not.

I tried using the following code:

```
NSTask *homeBrewTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[homeBrewTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
[homeBrewTask setArguments:@[ @"brew help" ]];
[homeBrewTask launch];
```

Can anyone help me on how I can check and install ffmpeg or brew using NSTask?

Comment: @TheNextman Not working.

Comment: [homeBrewTask setArguments:@[@"-c", @"brew help"]];

Comment: @TheNextman not working getting following error /bin/bash: brew: command not found